# Schematic review MAX20029ATIAV

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, buck

I am using a [MAX20029ATIAV](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX20029-MAX20029D.pdf) in my design for powering a [Quad Tunneling GMSL2/1 to CSI-2 Deserializer](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max96724.pdf).

MAX20029ATIAV is Quad Low-Voltage Step-Down DC-DC Converters.

My schematic is given below. May I know your valuable suggestions/comments?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks good to me.

My observations are:

1. LX1 and L140 ought to be connected in series.
2. Keep in mind that ceramic output caps are required.